# How to insert image in OpenOffice Document using Delphi

Tags: delphi, openoffice-writer

I am using approach mentioned in accepted solution of
[How to Search and Replace in odt Open Office document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806041/how-to-search-and-replace-in-odt-open-office-document)
for search and replace text in odt document using Delphi

now my requirement is replace text with image.
for example my odt file will have tags as "SHOW_CHART=ID", i will retrieve chart from DB for given ID as an image file and then replace it with "SHOW_CHART=ID".

So my question is how to insert image from a file to ODT document.
I found another link asking same question but using java.
[How to insert an image in to an openoffice writer document with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236515/how-to-insert-an-image-in-to-an-openoffice-writer-document-with-java)
but i don't know java.

Comment: There seems an incomplete attempt here https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=74202

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code was adapted from Listing 5.24 of [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).

```
ServiceManager := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager');
Desktop := ServiceManager.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');
NoParams := VarArrayCreate([0, -1], varVariant);
Document := Desktop.loadComponentFromURL('private:factory/swriter', '_blank', 0, NoParams);
Txt := Document.getText;
TextCursor := Txt.createTextCursor;
{TextCursor.setString('Hello, World!');}
Graphic := Document.createInstance('com.sun.star.text.GraphicObject');
Graphic.GraphicURL := 'file:///C:/path/to/my_image.jpg';
Graphic.AnchorType := 1; {com.sun.star.text.TextContentAnchorType.AS_CHARACTER;}
Graphic.Width := 6000;
Graphic.Height := 8000;
Txt.insertTextContent(TextCursor, Graphic, False);
```

More information on using OpenOffice with Pascal is at https://www.freepascal.org/~michael/articles/openoffice1/openoffice.pdf.

**EDIT**:

This code inserts `SHOW_CHART=123` and `SHOW_CHART=456` as an example.  Then it finds these strings and replaces them with the corresponding image.

```
Txt.insertString(TextCursor, 'SHOW_CHART=123' + #10, False);
Txt.insertString(TextCursor, 'SHOW_CHART=456' + #10, False);
SearchDescriptor := Document.createSearchDescriptor;
SearchDescriptor.setSearchString('SHOW_CHART=[0-9]+');
SearchDescriptor.SearchRegularExpression := True;
Found := Document.findFirst(SearchDescriptor);
While Not (VarIsNull(Found) or VarIsEmpty(Found) or VarIsType(Found,varUnknown)) do
begin
    IdNumber := copy(String(Found.getString), Length('SHOW_CHART=') + 1);
    Found.setString('');
    Graphic := Document.createInstance('com.sun.star.text.GraphicObject');
    If IdNumber = '123' Then
        Graphic.GraphicURL := 'file:///C:/path/to/my_image123.jpg'
    Else
        Graphic.GraphicURL := 'file:///C:/path/to/my_image456.jpg';
    Graphic.AnchorType := 1; {com.sun.star.text.TextContentAnchorType.AS_CHARACTER;}
    Graphic.Width := 6000;
    Graphic.Height := 8000;
    TextCursor.gotoRange(Found, False);
    Txt.insertTextContent(TextCursor, Graphic, False);
    Found := Document.findNext(Found.getEnd, SearchDescriptor);
end;
```

**EDIT 2**:

Embedding is explained in the next section of Andrew's document, Listing 5.26.

```
Bitmaps := Document.createInstance('com.sun.star.drawing.BitmapTable');
While...
    If IdNumber = '123' Then begin
        Bitmaps.insertByName('123Jpg', 'file:///C:/OurDocs/test_img123.jpg');
        Graphic.GraphicURL := Bitmaps.getByName('123Jpg');
    end Else begin
        Bitmaps.insertByName('456Jpg', 'file:///C:/OurDocs/test_img456.jpg');
        Graphic.GraphicURL := Bitmaps.getByName('456Jpg');
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim k for providing sample, it worked well for inserting a image in document. how can i insert an image at desired location in the document?

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Jim k

Comment: hi @Jim k, Although i accepted your asnwer but i am having issue as follows:
Inserted image always refer the local file, if i remove the local file the link is broken and on opening the odt document i loose the image , that i don't want, how to achieve that?

Comment: hi @Jim K I get Error "com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException" when it try to replace text with image in Document Header.

Comment: The header is likely to be different.  Ask a new question about the header and give example code that shows the problem.  Also add a link to this post, mentioning that it is a follow-up or related question.

Comment: Hello @Jim k
i posted a new question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57809463/how-to-search-text-tags-and-replace-with-image-in-header-footer-table-of-openoff